Interest Rate Swap versus Cash Bond
From the point of view of a leveraged fund manager, what is the benefit of buying a bond when the same could be expressed through an OIS swap? Assuming, of course that the swap is not mispriced i.e. no arb exists between the cash bond and the swap.
I am a buy side money manager  and experienced in trading equities and futures but starting out on interest rate swaps.
Thank you.

To execute a view on rates, I'd say there isn't (at least for sovereign bonds) - so long as u'r ok to run the asset swap spread risk. In fact, prior to the financial crisis, trading a derivative (i.e. a swap) was preferred over trading an asset (i.e. a bond) due to funding costs associated with holding an asset (especially if there was no repo market for the bond). However with changes in regulations in derivative collateralization/margining this is a lesser benefit.

If the goal is to change your interest rate sensitivity, then yet another instrument that some people prefer is rates or bonds futures, or even options.
The choice of rates instruments may depend on how your place of work allocates costs, which sometimes differs a lot from actual costs, and skews the preferences. Bonds are on balance sheet, you may be "charged" too much or too little for that, and for the costs of financing the bond position. But maybe the "charges" have nothing at all to do with your usage, and then you don't care. Likewise, to be able to use derivatives, someone needs to pay for one-time setup (e.g. ISDA agreement etc) and continuous costs (e.g. someone to look after margins and counterparty credit), and the people who benefit from the infrastructure may be paying too much or too little for their access/usage.
